# Linear Algebra system of equation book mistake?Linear Algebra by Fraleigh

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I think there's a mistake in my Linear Algebra text where it shows the systems of equation for a given matrix. I have posted the picture below. I don't see how the given matrix can be used to attain the given equation for w(3) and w(5).[image]

[image]

Comment: i am sorry. I realize this is the first time the book switches from row to column vector span. It makes sense that column vectors w(3) and w(5) can be spanned by the combination of others column vectors

Comment: Yes: when a matrix is in RREF, you can immediately read how to write nondominant columns as linear combinations of the dominant ones. Note that this reflects on the columns of the original matrix.

Comment: Thanks egreg. I didn't realize the relationship held for original matrix also.

Comment: It's a very nice result that helps in efficiently finding bases of subspaces when a spanning set is known. You reduce the matrix formed by those vectors (or their coordinate vectors with respect to some basis of the ambient space) and the columns corresponding to the dominant ones are a basis of the subspace, because linear relations are preserved through the row reduction process.